# How to create a free tfs server easily

Tags: c#, tfs

So, I want to share my DLL pack code and be able to collaborate in real time with a friend :) but I don't know how to upload my .sln file to the free tfs server.  can can anyone help?  Did some research, and couldn't find how :(

Comment: Use Dropbox and put a local Git repo there, then what you want can be easily achieved. You can also use GitHub/BitBucket/Visual Studio Team Services for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit unsure about if you already have a TFS server or not. So I included a link right below here where to get one if you don't.

Go to https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/ if you wanna use free TFS.

This is a very easy way to do this, as I assume you never done this before. But if you done some research you should know the Team Explorer in Visual studio

1. Create a project in your TFS and Go into your Visual Studio and connect
   to your TFS
2. "Map and Get" to a location on your computer. It will
   created a folder where you can decide what you want to add to your
   TFS Project(It should ask you when you connected, but if not you can
   find it Source Control Explorer)
3. Add your solution into that folder
4. If you go into Pending changes you should now have some "Detected
   add(s)" in the bottom at exclude changes. You wanna click on that
   and include all the files you want to share.

[image: Team Explorer Image]

Now your friend can do the first 2 steps and also have the same solution and stuff as you.

If you decide to use Git by any chance, is kinda the same process, just different names.

If you need more details on this, feel free to throw a comment. However if you done some basic research into this and already been playing around. There should be no issues at all. There are hundred of videos on youtube about TFS, How to set it up and much more.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! :DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

Comment: BTW i did start iwth a git repository and loaded it from there... i use github to upload folders cuz VS online doesnt support folders :|